# How to read the json file of a dynamical way in relation to their size structure

Tags: json, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have the following JSON file named `ProcessedMetrics.json` which is necessary read for send their values to some template:

```
     {
  "paciente": {
    "id": 1234,
    "nombre": "Pablo Andrés Agudelo Marenco",
    "sesion": {
      "id": 12345,
      "juego": [
        {
          "nombre": "bonzo",
          "nivel": [
            {
              "id": 1234,
              "nombre": "caida libre",
              "segmento": [
                {
                  "id": 12345,
                  "nombre": "Hombro",
                  "movimiento": [
                    {
                      "id": 1234,
                      "nombre": "flexion",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "___léeme___": "El array 'iteraciones' contiene las vitorias o derrotas con el tiempo en segundos de cada iteración",
              "iteraciones": [
                {
                  "victoria": true,
                  "tiempo": 120
                },
                {
                  "victoria": false,
                  "tiempo": 232
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Through of the following class based view I am reading a JSON file.

```
class RehabilitationSessionDetail(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = RehabilitationSession
    template_name = 'rehabilitationsession_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super(RehabilitationSessionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        is_auth=False

        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            is_auth=True

            with open('ProcessedMetrics.json') as data_file:
                session_data=json.loads(data_file.read())

            #Sending a data to template
                       context.update({'is_auth':is_auth,
                                       'session_data':session_data
                                     })
       return context
```

In my template `rehabilitationsession_detail.html` I put my tag of this way:

```
<td>{{session_data.paciente.sesion.juego}}</td>
```

Then I get the document json in my template

[image]

In my template, I want get the dictionary(before json document) values of a separate way such as follow:

[image]

The idea is that without matter the nested levels of the json document I can get the values. Sometimes, the json document will have more identation levels in their structure and other times will be a json document more simple

I would that independently of the json document size (if this have more than one item in your arrays) will be possible read and get all the values.

I  try accessing to the specific item from the `RehabilitationSessionDetail` view of this way:

```
segment = data["paciente"]["sesion"]["juego"][0]["nivel"][0]["segmento"][0]["nombre"]
```

And this works, but not always I will get the same json document structure.

In summary, How to can I get the values (nested and parents) of my json document for send them to the template?

I hope can be clear in my question. Any orientation is highly graceful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your question, with different JSON sizes you mean different array sizes? You can loop in the django template to get all the information out. So you would do for a nested visualisation:

```
{% for nest1 in data["patiente"]["sesion"]["juego"] %}
<li>{{ nest1["nombre"] }}</li>
{% for nest2 in nest2["nivel"] %}
etc...
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To get it as a table you would seperate the data and make a loop for each table column

```
<tr>
    {% for nest1 in data["patiente"]["sesion"]["juego"] %}
    <td>{{ nest1["nombre"] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>

<tr>
    {% for nest1 in data["patiente"]["sesion"]["juego"] %}
    {% for nest2 in nest2["nivel"] %}
    <td>{{ nest2["relevant_key"] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
etc...
```

because of the nested json data representation you template code will have to follow this nesting.

Hope I understood your question correctly and hope this helps.

Comment: @levllime thanks for your approach, this mean that I need make some loop iterations in each row/column. Is possible that I can have some performance situations? I will have that check this with some tool or some related ...

Comment: @bgarcial This is definitely not as fast as having an unnested data model in your json. A speedup would be to first convert the nested json lists into a unnested json before putting it in the django template.